# select case in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

for the following code

```
Dim mark As Integer

mark = InputBox("please enter your grade")
Select Case mark
    Case < 50
        MsgBox("fail")
    Case 50 To 64
        MsgBox("pass")
    Case 65 To 74
        MsgBox("good")
    Case 75 To 84
        MsgBox("very good")
    Case 85 To 1000
        MsgBox("excellent")
End Select
```

I intentionally defined grade as integer. So why when the grade is 49.5 , it outputs fail (which means that the grade has been rounded to the lowest integer) ? While on the other hand , when the grade is 64.5 it outputs "pass" which means that the grade has rounded to the highest integer ?

Comment: hmmm, grade being `49.5` should output "pass" and for `64.5` should output "good". I cannot replicate your issue. https://dotnetfiddle.net/H1v5b9

Comment: Put "Option Strict On" at the top of your code file.

Comment: @Aomine Try replicating it with an InputBox.

Comment: Do not guess what the automatic conversions of VB are doing. Instead, set `Option Strict On` and perform the conversions yourself. First convert the string from the InputBox to a `Double`, or better to a `Decimal`, and then use `Math.Round`, `Math.Ceil` or `Math.Floor`and convert the result to an Integer. Then you will know what happens.

Comment: Because it is not 49.5, it is a wee bit less.  Use Decimal instead of Double if you want predictable outcomes in 10 finger math.

Answer (score 0):

if 64.5 is giving "pass" its not getting rounded to the high as you said, it means its going to 64 (pass is from 50 to 64 so it makes sense)

Now about the rounding you can use Decimal.Round, it takes as params the number, the amount of decimals you want(in your case 0 decimals) and the mode to round

you should use a decimal var, but if you insist in using integer, just convertt the result of Decimal.Round to int

Answer (score 0):

Do not guess what the automatic conversions of VB are doing. Instead, set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) and perform the conversions yourself.

```
Dim input As String = InputBox("please enter your grade")
Dim grade As Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(input, grade) Then
    ' Now we know that the input is a valid decimal number.

    ' Here we control explicitly how we want to convert it to an Integer:
    Dim mark As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(grade, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))

    Select Case mark
        Case < 50
            MsgBox("fail")
        Case 50 To 64
            MsgBox("pass")
        Case 65 To 74
            MsgBox("good")
        Case 75 To 84
            MsgBox("very good")
        Case 85 To 1000
            MsgBox("excellent")
    End Select
End If
```

Also, `Decimal`, unlike `Double`, does not convert an input of `49.5` to something like `49.4999999999999999`.